# Chocolate baking bars vs. chocolate chips?

Tags: chocolate, melting-chocolate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use Chocolate Chips in place of Semi-sweet baking chocolate?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10130/can-i-use-chocolate-chips-in-place-of-semi-sweet-baking-chocolate)

Can I substitute chocolate baking bars for chocolate chips?  Usually the baking bars are so much more expensive.  I am going to be melting the chocolate, so I'd figure chocolate is chocolate, right?  However, I am worried about if when letting the chocolate set, if the results are going to be different or not (texture, shine, smoothness, etc). Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by chocolate baking bars? Proper stuff like Valrhona?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Hersheys-Baking-Pieces-Semi-Sweet-12-Ounce/dp/B000IN0EV4/ref=sr_1_6?s=grocery&ie=UTF8&qid=1308172656&sr=1-6 vs. http://www.amazon.com/Hersheys-Unsweetened-Baking-Chocolate-12CT/dp/B000P0MOIG/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=grocery&qid=1308172724&sr=1-1 ?

Comment: See the linked question - assuming you buy the same quality of each, they're pretty much the same, but a lot of the cheap chocolate chips may have other ingredients.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that if you're melting chocolate, it's fine to substitute chocolate bars - maybe even preferred. Chocolate chips are a much lower quality chocolate than real chocolate bars. (I've read that chocolate chips contain less cocoa butter, so that they hold their shape better in cookies - which also makes them harder to melt.) In general, I've found that when baking with chocolate, the higher the quality of the chocolate, the better the end product.